# Angularjs typeahead is not working. I want to both condition drop down and input

Tags: java, angularjs

**HTML Code**:

I am tying to use bothd condition in typeahead drop-down and input:

```
<div ng-controller="newFIncomeCtrl">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 in-inline err-group" show-errors>
        <label class="control-label">Bank Name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="item.bank" name="bName" tooltip="Bank Name" placeholder="Type Bank Name" typeahead="ban as ban.name for ban in banks | filter:$viewValue| limitTo:10" ng-change="change(item.bank)" ng-required=" true ">
    </div>
</div>
```

My First  Class `FixedIncome`:

```
public class FixedIncome extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {
    public static final String CUSTOMERINCOME = "customerincome";

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @DBRef
    private BankName bank;

    @NotNull
    @DBRef
    private Status status;

    private int amount;

    private DateTime investDate = null;


}
```

My Second class `BankName`:

```
public class BankName implements Serializable {

    public static final String BANK = "bank";
    public static final String BANKNAME_COLLECTION = "ag.bank";

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String statusRefId = "ACTIVE";


    private Date createdDate = new Date();

    private Date lastModifiedDate = new Date();

    @NotNull
    private String alias;
}
```

My am  getting this `error`:

> Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, >class com.advice.domain.BankName] from String value ('sdrttt'); no >single-String constructor/factory method
>   at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@35e53318; line: 1, column: 23] (through reference chain: com.advice.domain.portfolio.FixedIncome["bank"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.advice.domain.BankName] from String value ('sdrttt'); no single-String constructor/factory method
>    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@35e53318; line: 1, column: 23] (through reference chain: com.advice.domain.portfolio.FixedIncome["bank"])